# How can I get max record from every date in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have a table:

```
id,date,number
1,2016-08-11,2
2,2016-08-11,3
3,2016-08-11,1
4,2016-08-12,5
5,2016-08-13,8
6,2016-08-13,9
7,2016-08-13,2
```

How can i get this result by max number in each date?

```
id,date,number
2,2016-08-11,3
4,2016-08-12,5
6,2016-08-13,9
```

Comment: `SELECT id, date, max( number )
FROM table
GROUP BY date`

Answer (score 1):

You can execute this query in yii2.

```
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
$command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT id, date, max( number ) FROM table GROUP BY date');
$result = $command->queryAll();
```

Comment: How can i realize it with yii2, not mysql?

Comment: how about my edited answer ? vote if it helped, thanks !

Comment: I know, but it works as you want. Please vote if it helped, thanks !

Comment: Sorry man, i know this select and i know this trick, i want to get information from a model : )

Answer (score 0):

**ActvieRecord**

Declare public variable in model. say, `$numbers`

```
Table::find()->select("id, date, MAX('number') as numbers")->groupBy('date')->all();
```

Comment: MAX operation gives only one string, we can not group after that.